# Tem alguma forma mais eficiente de gerar lista de lista com o pandas?

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, lista, pandas

Alguém sabe alguma forma mais eficiente de fazer essa lista de lista com uma linha de excel? Pode até mudar a forma de escrever as informações no excel.

```
import pandas as pd
lista = pd.read_excel(r"contratos a fazer.xlsx")
for linha in lista.index:
    rotas=[]
    for i in range (3):
        municipio = str(lista.loc[linha, f"municipio{i+1}"])
        rota = str(lista.loc[linha, f"rota{i+1}"])
        turnos = str(lista.loc[linha, f"turnos{i+1}"])
        veiculo = str(lista.loc[linha, f"veiculo{i+1}"])
        placa = str(lista.loc[linha, f"placa{i+1}"])
        valor = str(lista.loc[linha, f"valor{i+1}"])
        item=[municipio, rota, turnos, veiculo, placa, valor]
        rotas.append(item)
    print(rotas)
```

Ele pega os dados dessa tabela:
[image: tabela de rotas]

Os dados da tabela são:

```
municipio1;rota1;turnos1;veiculo1;placa1;valor1;municipio2;rota2;turnos2;veiculo2;placa2;valor2;municipio3;rota3;turnos3;veiculo3;placa3;valor3
Teresina;Mocambinho;Manhã;Ônibus;PBE-0745; R$ 250,00 ;Timon;Centro;Tarde;Ônibus;PBE-0745; R$ 300,00 ;José de Feitas;Lagoa Nova;Noite;VAN;JHW-5893; R$ 280,00
```

<sup>[Tabela em excel no Onedrive](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ajh3KWTBDhCIh9k0eoiO2taFSt7jTQ?e=L6WOxu)</sup>

O resultado está dando:

```
[['Teresina', 'Mocambinho', 'Manhã', 'Ônibus', 'PBE-0745', '250'], ['Timon', 'Centro', 'Tarde', 'Ônibus', 'PBE-0745', '300'], ['José de Feitas', 'Lagoa Nova', 'Noite', 'VAN', 'JHW-5893', '280']]
```

Mas precisa ser escrito em apenas uma linha na tabela todas as rotas.

Comment: Você pode postar a tabela, ou parte dela, em txt ao invés de imagem. Pouparia trabalho de quem tenta ajudar.

Comment: Nilton, tente criar um exemplo [Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que mais pessoas possam tentar te ajudar

Comment: Tem como pegar 3 colunas da tabela, juntar em uma coluna só pra pegar os itens dessa coluna mesclada como se fosse uma lista? Pra já vir a lista pronta   da tabela sem precisar passar por esse FOR que adiciona item por item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Respondendo a pergunta:
> **Sim existe uma forma mais simples e pouco custosa da perspectiva de processamento de solucionar o problema.**

O seu problema se consiste em ler um arquivo de dados e juntar colunas cujo os nomes possuam o mesmo [prefixo gramatical](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefixo_gramatical) veja novamente sua amostra de dados:

| municipio1 | rota1 | turnos1 | veiculo1 | placa1 | valor1 | municipio2 | rota2 | turnos2 | veiculo2 | placa2 | valor2 | municipio3 | rota3 | turnos3 | veiculo3 | placa3 | valor3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Teresina | Mocambinho | Manhã | Ônibus | PBE-0745 | R$ 250,00 | Timon | Centro | Tarde | Ônibus | PBE-0745 | R$ 300,00 | José de Feitas | Lagoa Nova | Noite | VAN | JHW-5893 | R$ 280,00 |

Se analisarmos os nomes das colunas, esse nomes se constituem nos prefixos `municipio`, `rota`, `turnos`, `veiculo`, `placa`, `valor` seguidos de um número.

O algoritmo então é simples:

- Leia a fonte dos dados: no seu caso `pd.read_excel(r"contratos a fazer.xlsx")`'
- Crie um DataFrame vazio para receber resultado da reorganização dos dados.
- Crie uma lista dos prefixos: no seu caso `['municipio', 'rota', 'turnos', 'veiculo', 'placa', 'valor']`
- Itere por essa lista:

  - Com o auxilio da propriedades:

    - [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)
    - [`pandas.DataFrame.columns`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html)
      Mais o auxilio do métodos:
    - [`pandas.Series.str.startswith()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html)
    - [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

  1. Extraia uma amostra de dados cujo as colunas que possuam o mesmo prefixo
  2. Dessa amostra transforme a primeira linha numa [Serie](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/series.html)
  3. Dessa Serie descarte o índice e adicione ao DataFame de resultados.

```python
import pandas as pd

rdf = pd.read_excel(r"contratos a fazer.xlsx") #No meu código de testes fiz a leitura dos dados com pd.read_csv("teste.csv",sep=";")

df= pd.DataFrame()                             #Cria o DataFrame que receberá os resultados.

prefixos = ['municipio', 'rota', 'turnos', 'veiculo', 'placa', 'valor'] #Cria a lista de prefixos baseada nos dados.

#Para cada prefixo p...
for p in prefixos:
  # amostra de dados cujo as colunas que possuam o mesmo prefixo rdf.loc[:,rdf.columns.str.startswith(p)]
  # transforme a primeira linha numa Serie .iloc[0]
  # da Serie descarte o índice .reset_index(drop=True)
  df[p] = rdf.loc[:,rdf.columns.str.startswith(p)].iloc[0].reset_index(drop=True)

  
print(df)
```

Cujo o resultado:

```
        municipio        rota turnos veiculo     placa        valor
0        Teresina  Mocambinho  Manhã  Ônibus  PBE-0745   R$ 250,00 
1           Timon      Centro  Tarde  Ônibus  PBE-0745   R$ 300,00 
2  José de Feitas  Lagoa Nova  Noite     VAN  JHW-5893   R$ 280,00
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [Ideone](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/prefix#main.py)</sup>

Comment: Muito bom assim, acho que dessa forma pode ter inúmeros itens.

Comment: Augusto, você é meu ídolo. Sempre aprendo alguma coisa nova. Desta vez foi o `df.columns.str`. Não sabia ser possível aplicar o método `str` nas colunas.

Comment: @PauloMarques, obrigado eu por ter a honra de poder contribuir com você que conhece tanto de Pandas e Numpy.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar alguns métodos do pandas.

### Importando bibliotecas e criando base de teste

```
import pandas as pd

from io import StringIO

dados = StringIO("""municipio1;rota1;turnos1;veiculo1;placa1;valor1;municipio2;rota2;turnos2;veiculo2;placa2;valor2;municipio3;rota3;turnos3;veiculo3;placa3;valor3
Teresina;Mocambinho;Manhã;Ônibus;PBE-0745; R$ 250,00 ;Timon;Centro;Tarde;Ônibus;PBE-0745; R$ 300,00 ;José de Feitas;Lagoa Nova;Noite;VAN;JHW-5893; R$ 280,00 """)

df = pd.read_csv(dados, sep=";")
```

### Criando lista com DFs

```
lista_dfs = []

for i in range(1, 4):
    lista_dfs.append(df.loc[:, f"municipio{i}":f"valor{i}"])
```

### Padronizando nomes das colunas

```
colunas = ["municipio", "rota", "turnos", "veiculo", "placa", "valor"]

for df in lista_dfs:
    df.columns = colunas
```

### Concatenando DFs e gerando lista final

```
novo_df = pd.concat(lista_dfs)

lista_final = novo_df.to_records().tolist()
```

A vantagem deste processo é que sua planilha pode ter várias linhas.

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente isso que eu tava procurando. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema não está relacionado com o pandas, mas sim com a sua lógica. Você está criando uma lista nova (`item`) a cada iteração em `for i in range(3)` e depois adicionando essa lista `item` na lista `rota`.

Para você obter o que deseja, basta substituir a linha `rotas.append(item)` por `rotas.extend(item)` ou fazer o append de cada dado diretamente na lista `rotas`.

Outro ponto important, se a inicialização da lista `rotas` permanecer dentro de `for linha in lista.index`, todos os resultados armazenados sempre serão limpos e você conseguirá acessar apenas a última linha lida da sua planilha.

Comment: Desculpa, não consegui entender a diferença de `[rota1, rota2, rota3]` para `[['Teresina', 'Mocambinho', 'Manhã', 'Ônibus', 'PBE-0745', '250'], ['Timon', 'Centro', 'Tarde', 'Ônibus', 'PBE-0745', '300'], ['José de Feitas', 'Lagoa Nova', 'Noite', 'VAN', 'JHW-5893', '280']]`. Me parece ser exatamente o que você descreveu.

Comment: Mas eu preciso que seja mesmo uma lista de lista [item1,item2,item3], e cada rota seja [municipio, rota, turnos, veiculo, placa, valor], ai eu não se tem um jeito de tirar do excel uma lista dentro de outra lista de algum jeito mais fácil. E ele tem que apagar mesmo a lista depois de usar porque ele vai preencher um documento e depois outro, por isso também preciso que no excel todas as rotas fiquem em uma linha só.

Comment: E é, eu consegui esse resultado depois de bater muita cabeça, mas eu imagino que deve ter uma forma mais fácil e organizada de fazer transportar a tabela em uma lista de lista. Não sei se tem alguma função no pandas que pegue colunas do Excel e transforme em listas por exemplo. Muito obrigado porque tentar me ajudar irmão.